# store json object field in Solr

Tags: json, indexing, solr

I'm new to Solr, I want to index a the following json object which contain a field that is json object itself. So when I use the schema-less mode, I get this erro:

```
{
    "name": "BURGER KING", 
    "phone": "+(1)-(403)-2153451", 
    "categories": ["fast food", "restaurant"], 
    "classifications": [
        {
            "code": "RESTAURANT", 
            "names": [
                 {
                     "nameLocale": "en-US", 
                     "name": "restaurant"
                  }, {
                     "nameLocale": "en-US", 
                     "name": "fast food"
                  }
             ]
        }
    ], 
    "location": "51.06652,-114.10822"
}

"msg":"Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START at [122], field=classifications"
```

Does anyone have any idea what's the best way to do this?

P.S. when I indexed the same document in linux using "bin/post", it automatically flattened the json object without any error. But when I'm indexing it in windows using "post.jar" it arises this error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bin/post` utility in Solr uses `org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool` to submit documents. When running the `post` utility, it'll output the complete command line before submitting the documents.

```
[..]/bin/java -classpath [..]solr-core-7.3.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=foo -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool ../example/films/films.json
```

You can then use the same command under Windows, or you can use cygwin or the Ubuntu on Windows toolset to run the `post` tool itself (if you have the git bash application installed, that will give you the same environment as well).